# Partition problem where partition are in increasing order.

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, recursive-algorithms, dynamic-programming

For given $n$ and $S$, how many possible combinations are there such that:

$x_1 + x_2 + .. + x_n = S $ $\forall i, x_i \leq x_{i+1}$ $\&$ $x_i \geq 1$

For example, if $n$ = 3 and $S$ = 5, there are 2 possible combination:

- 1 + 1 + 3
- 1 + 2 + 2

Comment: These are called partitions with restricted number of parts, denoted by $p_n(S)$ in the notation of the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts. It is customary to write the parts in **decreasing** order: $x_1\ge x_2\ge\cdots$. For $n=3$ see https://oeis.org/A069905.